# Export Translations not exporting web part titles

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019, language-pack

I am enabling multi-language Sharepoint communication site on Sharepoint Server 2019. I have enabled the English as main language and Arabic as the secondary language. I have added Events web part and changed the default title of the events web part.

[image]

However, when I export translations for Arabic by choosing No for "Only export text that is not translated", I cannot see the events title in the .resx file.

[image]

Please help in translating web part titles

Answer (score 0):

Is this a classic events webpart or a modern one?  Classic webparts support MUI, Modern ones do not.  Also the original title of the webpart from the template is not exported, you have to change it first.

Comment: This is the modern one. I changed the web part title before exporting the translations